# Duda con PLSQL Oracle

Tags: plsql, cursor

Tengo una duda con un procedimiento en Oracle.

Si tengo un parametro de entrada solo, por ejemplo esto:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE datos (ciudad_comp IN compradores.ciudad%TYPE)
IS
    CURSOR codigo_comprador IS
        select codigocomprador from compradores
        where ciudad=ciudad_comp;

    CComp codigo_comprador%ROWTYPE;
```

Como puedo crear otro cursor, para que también pueda utilizar el código del comprador del primer cursor en el siguiente cursor?
Por ejemplo, esto no hace caso a pedidos.codigocomprador=CComp.codigocomprador:

```
        CURSOR compras IS
            select sum(cantidad*preciounidad) as importe
from detallepedidos, pedidos
        where pedidos.codigopedido = detallepedidos.codigopedido
        AND pedidos.codigocomprador=CComp.codigocomprador

        CCompras compras%ROWTYPE;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También a que leas [ask] y finalmente, que edites tu pregunta y añadas el mensaje exacto de error que estás obteniendo. Un saludo.

Comment: No obtengo error, funciona pero mal. Ya que ignora CComp.codigocomprador

Comment: Mencionas en tu pregunta que da error. Si no te da error, creo entonces que es mejor que publiques un fragmento más grande de código y que expliques el resultado que esperas ver y el que estás obteniendo. Repito mi recomendación de leer [ask], pues cubrir esas recomendaciones aumentará tus probabilidades de obtener ayuda. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que recibir el parámetro dentro de tu primer cursor dentro de una variable declarada y pasarla dentro de la estructura de tu nuevo cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE datos (ciudad_comp IN compradores.ciudad%TYPE)
IS
    CURSOR codigo_comprador IS
        select codigocomprador from compradores
        where ciudad=ciudad_comp;
   cod_comprador compradores.codigo_comprador%type;
   
   #nuevo cursor que recibe variable
   cursor new_cursor(codi_comprador in compradores.codigo_comprador%type)
   is
   #select something
   ;
   new_variable varchar2(400);
begin
open codigo_comprador;
loop
fetch codigo_comprador into cod_comprador ;
#ahora si podemos usar la variable cod_comprador para  pasarla a un nuevo cursor
open new_cursor(cod_comprador);
fetch new_cursor into new_variable;
close new_cursor;
end loop;

end datos;
```

Te recomendaría que todos los datos "variables" o "dependientes" que uses dentro de tus cursores los pases como datos en la estructura del cursor.